# accessing json file with jquery, relative path error

Tags: jquery, json, relative-path

Files are on server. File structure looks like this:

```
../index.html
../js/data.json
../js/insert.js
```

I need to access this json file. I tried with this in insert.js

```
$.get('data.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and i got

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access.

When i use absolute path to JSON file, it works just fine. I need it to work with relative path. What is wrong?

Comment: So your files are 1 directory up from your base path?

Comment: Your $.get is trying to go to the domain data.json (as in, www.data.json) and pull information from there.  That's why you're getting the XSS error.  You need to use a relative path, such as $.get('/js/data.json').

Comment: Path is clearly wrong but that is a CORS error which is strange in this case. Are you trying to open this page from `file://` protocol? Or loading page on different port than server?

Comment: So this should look like that:
 `$.get('/js/data.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);   
    });`  ?
This still dont work, same error. That page is deployed on web server and I am opening it via Chrome. I am afraid i dont know what You are asking about.

Comment: In browser dev tools network see what the actual url used is and if it differs from expected.

Comment: You were right. There was some strange urls pointing to things that were never there. I cleaned everything on server and now it works with what Scottie gave.
`$.get('/js/data.json', function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: Curious what you did see . Whole thing really doesn't make sense although original path was definitely wrong, but not wrong enough to get that error

Answer (score 0):

Path was wrong. It should look like that:

```
$.get('/js/data.json', function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

if file tree is like that:

```
../index.html
../js/data.json
../js/insert.js
```